# Getting error to create bundle in symofny 6.0

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I am trying to create a bundle in Symfony 6.0.20. When adding that bundle in  www\Acme\config\bundle.php it's showing the following error.

> #message: """
> Attempted to load class "AcmeTestBundle" from namespace "Acme\TestBundle".\n
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
> """

Bundle file
www\Acme\src\TestBundle\AcmeTestBundle.php

```html
<?php
//symfony composer dump-autoload

namespace Acme\TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class AcmeTestBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    
}
```

www\Acme\config\bundle.php

```html
<?php

 return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Acme\TestBundle\AcmeTestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

coposer.js

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Acme\\TestBundle\\": "src/TestBundle/"
        }
    },
"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/",
            "Acme\\TestBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Could you please share your composer.json ?

Comment: Specifically you need to insure that the Acme namespace is defined in the autoload section of composer.json.  You might also need to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Thanks both of you. It looks working fine after adding the namespace in the autoload section of composer.js. I have shared the autoload section of composer.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to remove App namespace from both side as you try to register two different namespace where first could handle other the one.

```json
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Your class namespace still be:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class AcmeTestBundle extends AbstractBundle
{  
}
```

If you need two different namespace in src folder, you should create two folders in your `src/` folder (ex: `src/App` and `src/Acme`):

```json
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/App/",
            "Acme\\": "src/Acme/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/App/",
            "Acme\\Tests\\": "tests/Acme/",
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Your class namespace still be:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class AcmeTestBundle extends AbstractBundle
{  
}
```

Comment: Well no. You need one namespace for the App code and one for the bundle. Your initial suggestion is just plain wrong. Your second suggestion about two directories is a good one but renaming the App source directory involves more than just pointing to a namespace.  So it will blow up as well.  The OP posted their solution of using `src/TestBundle` which is also going to cause problems which I suspect they have already discovered. Using a directory with a name like `src-acme-bundle` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Th first solution was more if he want to have only one namespace only for the bundle so it's not wrong. And for the second, you just said that it will cause problems without saying which one. It will be useful to explain which kind of error we could get with ? As in my actual work we are using like 30 differrents bundles with their own namespace (unfortunatly a legacy project) and we don't have problem at all but if we face one your explanation could help.

Comment: I have another bundle and in composer "Vle\\VleBundle\\":"src/Vle/VleBundle/". bundle class name VleBundle.php but it generates the error.. Compile Error: Cannot declare class Vle\VleBundle\VleBundle, because the name is already in use

Comment: I have found the solution.  exclude the - '../src/VleBundle' from App namespace in serverices.php